# Custom fileextension for document based application

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data, document-based

I have a document based application that makes use of core data. Basically the file it is saving it a sqlite file with the ending `.binary`.

I would need to change this ending to a custom ending so that it is recognized by the users. For example .suv2 (indicating the program name and the version)

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: You already set the file extension once, to `.binary`. If you want to change it to something else, you add the new extension in the same place that you added the old one.

Comment: i did not set it once.. it is default, and by default it has binary, sqlite, and another one i dont recall.